# IE localeCompare strange for string with minus sign

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
> "-1".localeCompare("2") 
< -1
> "-5".localeCompare("2") 
< 1
```

How does it work? Not like number, not string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently IE ignores certain nonalphanumeric characters like the minus sign ("-") in locale dependent comparisons, and only regards them when it comes to break ties between similar words.

Rules for locale dependent comparison are not strictly specified, but presumably, the rationale behind this is to sort "nonzero" before "non-zero" but after "non-adjacent".

Comment: I need this function to compare unicode char instead of english, so i have no idea to compare:{ "-AAA" "-BBB" "AAA" "BBB"  } as correct order in IE?

Comment: @progame If I understand your problem, you may try to convert both strings to lowercase with `a = a.toLowerCase(); b = b.toLowerCase();` and then compare them by character: `a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0`. If this doesn't help, submit a new post.